# Numerical dictionary keys as placeholders when printing strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting

I have the following code:

```
board_dic = {
    0: '_',
    1: '_',
    2: '_',
    3: '_',
    4: '_',
    5: '_',
    6: '_',
    7: '_',
    8: '_',
}

print("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|".format(**board_dic)
```

The output when running is:

```
line 28, in <module>
    print("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|".format(**board_dic))
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple
```

I can't find a solution to this anywhere. If I was to replace the keys in `board_dic` to strings, such as `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc. and replace the placeholders in the print statement to `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc. then my print statement would execute without any issues. However, it seems that the problem is specifically with numerical key dictionary values.

Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you need this result?
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what to look for it is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> The field_name itself begins with an arg_name that is either a number or a keyword. **If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument**, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, … in sequence, they can all be omitted (not just some) and the numbers 0, 1, 2, … will be automatically inserted in that order. Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, **it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10'** or ':-]') within a format string.

In simple terms, `'{0} {1}'.format(...)` means "replace `{0}` with the first positional argument and `{1}` with the second positional argument of `format(...)`.

Positional arguments are those that are passed without specifying the parameter name in the function call. For example in `format(1, 2, c=3)`, `1` and `2` are positional argument and `c=3` is a keyword argument.

But the `**board_dic` syntax specifies keyword arguments! `format(**board_dic)` is equivalent to `format(0='_', 1='_', 2='_', ...)`<sup>1</sup> and there are *no* positional arguments. Therefore, using `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, etc., to get the first, second, third, etc., positional argument, fails.

In order to pass a dictionary with integer keys to `format`, you can use this:

```
print("|{d[0]}|{d[1]}|{d[2]}|\n|...".format(d=board_dic))
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Numbers not being allowed as keywords is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

When using format-strings, placeholders like `{1}` represent the nth argument of "format()". This is different from named keyword-arguments. Using `**board_dic` will explode them into keyword-arguments. This is the reason it does not work as expected.

Instead you need to use positional arguments using a single `*`. But then you are confronted with a different issue: Dictionary ordering has only been made part of the language spec in Python 3.7 as far as I remember. It was already stable in previous versions, but that was an implementation detail and was not guaranteed in other versions (pypy, jython, ...).

So we need to sort it to be 100% sure this works.

As the keys are numerical, we can simply sort on `board_dic.items()`. This will give us a stable replacement.

We then need to extract the effective values. We can do this with a simple list-comprehension.

After that change we are - as long as the dictionary does not contain any missing numbers - 100% sure the output will be correct.

We can use the resulting list in `.format()` using a single "positional-argument-expansion".

```
board_dic = {
    0: '_',
    1: '_',
    2: '_',
    3: '_',
    4: '_',
    5: '_',
    6: '_',
    7: '_',
    8: '_',
}

values = [value for _, value in sorted(board_dic.items())]

print("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|".format(*values))
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert the dict values to positional arguments for the `str.format` method using their keys, you can map a `range` of the length of the dict to the `get` method of the dict and unpack the outputting sequence as arguments:

```
print("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|".format(*map(board_dic.get, range(len(board_dic)))))
```